# Swapping / rearranging of columns and its values based on inputs using Unix scripts

Tags: awk

Team,

I have an requirement of changing /ordering the column of csv files based on inputs .

example :

Datafile (source File) will be always with standard column and its values example :

```
PRODUCTCODE,SITE,BATCHID,LV1P_DESCRIPTION
MK3,Biberach,15200100_3,Biologics Downstream
MK3,Biberach,15200100_4,Sciona Upstream
MK3,Biberach,15200100_5,Drag envois
MK3,Biberach,15200100_8,flatsylio
MK3,Biberach,15200100_1,bioCovis
```

these columns (PRODUCTCODE,SITE,BATCHID,LV1P_DESCRIPTION) will be standard for source files and what i am looking for solution to format this and generate new file with the columns which we preferred .

Note : Source / Data file will be always comma delimited

Example : if I pass PRODUCTCODE,BATCHID as input then i would like to have only those column and its data extracted from source file and generate new file .

Something like script_name <output_column> <Source_File_name> <target_file_name>

target file example :

```
PRODUCTCODE,BATCHID
MK3,15200100_3
MK3,15200100_4
MK3,15200100_5
MK3,15200100_8
MK3,15200100_1
```

if i pass output_column as "LV1P_DESCRIPTION,PRODUCTCODE" then out file should be like below

```
LV1P_DESCRIPTION,PRODUCTCODE
Biologics Downstream,MK3
Sciona Upstream,MK3
Drag envios,MK3
flatsylio,MK3
bioCovis,MK3
```

It would be great if any one can help on this.

I have tried using some awk scripts (got it from some site)  but it was not working as expected , since i don't have unix knowledge finding difficulties to modify this .

awk code:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}

NR==1 {
    split(c, ca, ",")
    for (i = 1 ; i <= length(ca) ; i++) {
        gsub(/ /, "", ca[i])
        cm[ca[i]] = 1
    }
    for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) {
        if (cm[$i] == 1) {
            cc[i] = 1
        }
    }
    if (length(cc) == 0) {
        exit 1
    }
}

{
    ci = ""
    for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) {
        if (cc[i] == 1) {
            if (ci == "") {
                ci = $i
            } else {
                ci = ci "," $i
            }
        }
    }
    print ci
}
```

the above code is saves as Remove.awk and this will be called by another scripts  as below

```
  var1="BATCHID,LV2P_DESCRIPTION" 
  ## this is  input fields values used for testing
    
    awk -f Remove.awk -v c="${var1}" RESULT.csv > test.csv
```

Comment: Please fix your samples with CODE TAGS for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: i just formatted the samples

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: firstly i don't have good knowledge in UNIX scripting and work more cloud integration . the below code something i have used by saving it as .awk file but its failing when i have more 4-5 fields in my datafile .

Comment: BEGIN {
 FS = ","
}

NR==1 {
 split(c, ca, ",")
 for (i = 1 ; i <= length(ca) ; i++) {
  gsub(/ /, "", ca[i])
  cm[ca[i]] = 1
 }
 for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) {
  if (cm[$i] == 1) {
   cc[i] = 1
  }
 }
 if (length(cc) == 0) {
  exit 1
 }
}

{
 ci = ""
 for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) {
  if (cc[i] == 1) {
   if (ci == "") {
    ci = $i
   } else {
    ci = ci "," $i
   }
  }
 }
 print ci
}

Comment: var1="BATCHID,LV2P_DESCRIPTION,SITE,"

awk -f Remove.awk -v c="${var1}" RESULT.csv > test.csv

Comment: added the the scripts details  which i have tried

Answer (score 0):

The following GNU awk solution should meet your objectives:

```
awk -F, -v flds="LV1P_DESCRIPTION,PRODUCTCODE" 'BEGIN { split(flds,map,",") } NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { map1[$i]=i } } { printf "%s",$map1[map[1]];for(i=2;i<=length(map);i++) { printf ",%s",$map1[map[i]] } printf "\n" }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F, -v flds="LV1P_DESCRIPTION,PRODUCTCODE" '                        # Pass the fields to print as a variable field
   BEGIN { 
           split(flds,map,",")                      # Split fld into an array map using , as the delimiter
         } 
   NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
              map1[$i]=i                            # Loop through the header and create and array map1 with the column header as the index and the column number the value
           } 
         }
         { printf "%s",$map1[map[1]];                # Print the first field specified (index of map)
           for(i=2;i<=length(map);i++) { 
             printf ",%s",$map1[map[i]]              # Loop through the other field numbers specified, printing the contents
           } 
           printf "\n" 
          }' file
```

Comment: Hi  Raman , thanks for you reply ! i have tested the code  and its working fine but there is a problem in my side , i will not able to find out the column position in my existing process rather i will get column names like this  var1="BATCHID,LV2P_DESCRIPTION" . Not sure is this something you can help ?. I will also try to get the positions  with in my process by doing some lookup logic  so that i can use your code as such.

Comment: and other point i have notices - above  solution expect comma at end of the line in file , if note its going to next line LV2P_DESCRIPTION,SITE,BATCHID,
dsscs,SITE,batch123,

Comment: OK, I've amended the answer to find the column numbers and use them accordingly. I'm not sure what you mean about "expect comma at the end of the file" I have used your sample data and there are no commas at the end.

Comment: thanks Raman for the great helps , i will check this in some time and update you .

Comment: Hello Raman. Not sure anything wrong i am doing here , sow how i was not able to get the results correctly

Comment: - the below is results ( its actually printing all columns from source file)

Comment: [x2infacloud@inhas65350 BIOBU_INT]$ awk -F, -v flds="LV1P_DESCRIPTION,PRODUCTCODE" 'BEGIN { split(flds,map,",") } NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { map1[$i]=i } } { printf "%s",$map1[map[1]];for(i=2;i<=length(map);i++) { printf ",%s",$map1[map[i]] } printf "\n" }' RESULT.csv
,PRODUCTCODESITE,BATCHID,LV1P_DESCRIPTION
,MK3Biberach,15200100_3,Biologics Downstream
,MK3Biberach,15200100_4,Sciona Upstream
,MK3Biberach,15200100_5,Drag envois
,MK3Biberach,15200100_8,flatsylio
MK3,Biberach,15200100_1,bioCovis,MK3
[x2infacloud@inhas65350 BIOBU_INT]$

Comment: It works fine with the sample data posted. Can you make sure that the first line contains the headers and that the columns are comma separated.

Comment: Hi Raman, I have tested the code it working fine most cases except when i pass last header column as input example :  source files i have these header and data . -> PRODUCTCODE,SITE,BATCHID,LV1P_DESCRIPTION   and when want to extract only this ->LV1P_DESCRIPTION    Data   . This scenario its return whole file set instead of that specific column  data  but it will work if i pass any other column.

Comment: i think issue when i pass last column as input and some how unable to split  - I guess , unable to split since there is no comma at the end of the last field .  i have tested adding comma at end of source file and it works but in my case files will not be having any comma at the end of the line (its comma delimited csv so comma will be only between field not at the end) . Is this something you can help ? it would great and and i can use this solution as overall it really work well   .